# Parallel ajax requests with Ember.js and Ember Data

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data with a custom Adapter to query a JSON endpoint. I've noticed that although my app is set up to make Ajax requests in parallel, Ember will always make them in series.

So for example:

```
App.ModelA.query({args})
App.ModelB.query({args})
```

will result in ModelB's query coming *after* ModelA is complete. As well, the views dependent on ModelA will not update until both ModelA and ModelB have returned.

I'm wondering if there is something built into Ember Data to effect this? (i.e. as a precaution for avoiding race conditions?)

Comment: in which function are you calling the methods? from a route model hook?

Comment: I started off calling them in setupController() but at this point I'm in the console. If I call them one after the other, without fail the ajax requests will be in series rather than parallel.

Comment: and furthermore, the views will not update until all the queries return.. Trying to understand if there are any fundamental reasons for this behaviour and any potential workarounds to at least let views update between queries?

Answer (score 1):

My bad!! This had to do with a 3rd party library that was used in the custom adapter! Essentially the calls to the library were being queued, independently of Ember.Data!